# Создание производных классов WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

При изучение системы компоновки WPF у меня возникла куча вопросов, мне казалось что я разобрался с ними, до того момента пока не попытался сам сделать пару классов,поэкспериментировать. Вот тут я и понял, что абсолютно ничего не понимаю.

Вот маленький простой класс, я даже не могу понять почему он не работает:

```
    class Block : FrameworkElement
    {
        Rectangle block;
        public Brush Fill
        {
            get => block.Fill;
            set => block.Fill = value;
        }
        public Block()
        {
            block = new Rectangle();
            AddVisualChild(block);
            AddLogicalChild(block);
        }
        protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
        {
            block.Measure(new Size(Width,Height));
            return block.DesiredSize;
        }
        protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
        {
            block.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(0,0),finalSize));
            return finalSize;
        }
    }

    class A : Window
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            new Application().Run(new A());
        }
        public A()
        {
            Block b = new Block();
            b.Fill = Brushes.Black;
            b.Height = b.Width = 10;
            b.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
            b.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
            Content = b;
        }
    }
```

`DesiredSize = (0;0)`

Зачем нужно два метода `Measure` и `MeasureOverride`, если `Measure` вызывает `MeasureOverride`? (аналогично для `Arrange`)

Вызовы `Add(Logical|Visual)Child` дают поддержку маршрутизации и наследования значений зависимых свойств? Связь между `RenderSize` и `availableSize`?
Когда наследоваться от `FrameworkElement`, и когда от `UIElement`?
Вызывается ли `RenderSize` при создании объекта?
Зачем вызывать `AddLogicalChild` для элемента который не будет обрабатывать событию и влиять на "логику"?
Как вообще элемент без `OnRender` отрисовывает дочерние элементы?

Если `HorizontalAlignment` и `VerticalAlignment` = `Center`, то `availablesize` равен нулю, значит какое значение `sizedesired` не верни, оно все равно урежется?

Пока не попытался все казалось таким простым и ясным...
Есть какие-то общие, четкие правила когда и что нужно переопределять?

Comment: я полностью запутался

Answer (score 3):

Вы понимаете вообще зачем вам нужно наследовать от `FrameworkElement`?

А нужно это для создания собственных (кастомных) элементов управления.
Наследуемый класс зависит от ваших задач:

- Наследуйте от `FrameworkElement` когда нужно нарисовать его содержимое "с нуля" (с использованием `DrawingContext` через переопределение `OnRender`).
- Наследуйте от `UIElement` если желаете составить элемент из других контролов

Вообще, ответ на все вопросы есть тут: [WPF layout: Measure и Arrange](https://habrahabr.ru/post/135990/); а так же здесь: [Understanding MeasureOverride and ArrangeOverride](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1034445/Understanding-MeasureOverride-and-ArrangeOverride)

А по повожу вашего нерабочего `FrameworkElement` могу сказать следующее:

1. Гуглили плохо ([Google: wpf inherit frameworkelement](https://www.google.ru/search?newwindow=1&biw=1920&bih=950&q=wpf+inherit+frameworkelement&oq=wpf+inherit+framewo&gs_l=psy-ab.3.0.0i22i30k1l2.8531047.8541967.0.8544541.19.17.2.0.0.0.379.2407.0j1j8j1.10.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..7.12.2439...0j0i67k1j0i13k1.ODal0XPZTwc)).
2. Как я уже сказал, `FrameworkElement` рисуется "с нуля". Ну например:

   ```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Content = new MyFrameWorkElement();
        }
    }

   public class MyFrameWorkElement : FrameworkElement
   {
       Size _size;
       public MyFrameWorkElement()
       {
           this.SizeChanged += (o, e) =>
           {
               _size = e.NewSize;
               this.InvalidateVisual(); // cause a render
           };
       }

       protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
       {
           base.OnRender(drawingContext);
           drawingContext.DrawRectangle(
               Brushes.Blue, 
               new Pen(Brushes.Red, 2), 
               new Rect(1, 1, _size.Width / 2, _size.Height / 2));
           drawingContext.DrawEllipse(
               Brushes.Green, 
               new Pen(Brushes.Yellow, 2), 
               center: new Point(_size.Width / 2, _size.Height / 2), 
               radiusX: _size.Width / 4, 
               radiusY: _size.Height / 4);
           var txt = new FormattedText(
               "Foobar",
               System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
               FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
               new Typeface("Courier new"),
               21,
               Brushes.Red);
           drawingContext.DrawText(txt, 
               new Point(_size.Width / 2, _size.Height / 2)
               );
       }
   }
   ```
3. Для создания собственных элементов управления я вообще использую `UIElement` (и вам советую): [UserControl](https://professorweb.ru/my/WPF/Template/level18/18_5.php).

Comment: UIElement сам наследует FrameworkElement добавляя в него разные "полезности", а так же добавляет привязку, поддержку анимаций и стилей.
А разве не наоборот?

Comment: Сори. Ошибочка вышла. Тяжёлый сегодня вышел денёк) Хотел выяснить для вас конкретные отличия именно для ваших целей и что-то был спутал этой статейкой: https://professorweb.ru/my/WPF/base_WPF/level1/1_7.php (а схема то в обратном порядке).

Answer (score 2):

итак, рабочий класс :

```
class Block : FrameworkElement
{
    Rectangle block;
    public Brush Fill
    {
        get => block.Fill;
        set => block.Fill = value;
    }
    public Block()
    {
        AddVisualChild(block);
        AddLogicalChild(block);
        block = new Rectangle();
    }
    protected override Visual GetVisualChild(int index)
    {
        if (index == 0) return block;
        else throw new Exception("index");
    }
    protected override int VisualChildrenCount => 1;
    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        block.Arrange(new Rect(finalSize));
        return finalSize;
    }
}
```

*Почему не работал предыдущий класс?*
Класс Block не имеет собственного визуального представления, так как OnRender не переопределен. Он является лишь оболочкой над визуальными объектами(экземпляры классов производных от Visual). 
Для того чтобы элемент стал оболочкой для визуальных объектов, он должен

- унаследоваться от [FrameworkElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.frameworkelement(v=vs.110).aspx)
- переопределить свойство [VisualChildrenCount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.visualchildrencount(v=vs.110).aspx)
- метод [GetVisualChild](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.getvisualchild(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [MeasureOverride](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.measureoverride(v=vs.110).aspx)(см примечания 1)&[ArrangeOverride](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.arrangeoverride(v=vs.110).aspx)(эти два метода нужны всем элементам с дочерними элементами)
- и возможно [OnRender](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.uielement.onrender(v=vs.110).aspx)(см примечания 2).

Соответственно предыдущая версия класса не работала из-за того что не были реализованы VisualChildrenCount и GetVisualChild, необходимые для отображения визуальных объектов.

---

*примечания*

1. В этом классе не нужно переопределять MeasureOverride, так как подходит реализация по умолчанию, возвращающая (0;0). На Measure стадии проводиться опрос дочерних элементов на предмет того какой размер они ожидают получить, но *block* не ожидает никакого размера, он банально растягивается по размерам своей оболочки, так как Horizontal|VerticalAlignment у него по умолчанию равны Stretch. Например если экземпляру Block выставить размеры явно, то и его дочерний элемент получит такой размер, а если размеры не выставлять, то экземпляр Block растянется на все свободное пространство, и его дочерний элемент примет размер этого самого пространства.
2. OnRender стоит переопределять если оболочка должна иметь некоторый внешний вид, но нужно учитывать что все нарисованное этим методом будет находится под визуальными объектами.